# How to stop DVD drive from spinning?

Tags: dvd-burning

I was using [Hamster Free Burning Studio](http://www.hamstersoft.com/free-burning-studio/) to burn a DVD, on the first run it crashed. But my DVD is still spinning inside my laptop. Is there any ***non-physical*** (so no paper clip in the tiny hole method) ways to stop this?

I tried long-press the eject button, I've also tried running the software again and pressing the eject button within the software.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily disable the drive in device manager...

Right-click / disable

Then re-enable it after a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Power off the laptop. Then power it back on - the drive will likely spin up as it boots (and possibly as windows loads to check what's on the disk) but then should come to a stop.

Then eject the disk :)

If it doesn't stop spinning even after a reboot, power off the laptop, and then use the paperclip hole to eject it once it's stopped spinning while being powered off.